# functional analysis (Faedo Galerkin Method)

Tags: approximation, galerkin-methods

if \begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(u^{0\nu },u^{1\nu },v^{0\nu },v^{1\nu },p^{0\nu },q^{0\nu }) \rightarrow (u^{0},u^{1},v^{0},v^{1},p^{0},q^{0})  \\ \text{strongly in } (H^1_\gamma \cap H^2(0,L)\times H^1_\gamma \times (H^1_\gamma \cap H^2(0,L))\times H^1_\gamma  \times H^1(0,L)\times H^1_\gamma).
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

where $L>0$, $H^1_\gamma = \{ \Phi \in H^1(0,L) \ \Phi (0)=0 \}$ and $ (u^{0\nu },u^{1\nu },v^{0\nu },v^{1\nu },p^{0\nu },q^{0\nu })$ is the initial data of the problem.

We fix $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$. If K=$\{ u^{0\nu },u^{1\nu },v^{0\nu } ,v^{1\nu },p^{0\nu },q^{0\nu }\}$ is a linearly independent set.

How costruct a basis depending of $K$ for write the solution in the following form

$$u^{\nu m}(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\alpha^{j\nu m}(t)w_j^{\nu}(x),\hspace{1.4cm}v^{\nu m}(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\beta^{j\nu m}(t)w_j^{\nu}(x),$$
$$p^{\nu m}(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\gamma^{j\nu m}(t)w_j^{\nu}(x),\hspace{0.3cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.3cm} q^{\nu m}(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sigma^{j\nu m}(t)w_j^{\nu}(x).$$

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What have you tried?

Comment: @epimorphic the problem take this form $u_{tt}-u_{xx}-v_x+v_{tt}-v_{xx}+u_x+v+p_x+p_t+q_x+v_{tx}+q_t+q+p_x=0$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t)=v(0,t)=q(0,t)=0.$